# Unable to save records in csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, request, webdriver

Not Saving 75 records in csv file but it print records in terminal
website:https://sehat.com.pk/categories/Over-The-Counter-Drugs/Diarrhea-and-Vomiting-/?sort=alphaasc&page=2

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
for page_number in range(1, 6):
    url = f'https://sehat.com.pk/categories/Over-The-Counter-Drugs/Diarrhea-and-Vomiting-/?sort=featured&page='+str(page_number)
    r = requests.get(url)
    #time.sleep(6)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-md-12 pr-0 pl-0')
    suit =[]
    for property in content:
        
        names = property.find('div',class_='col-md-12 d-table-cell align-middle')
        name= names.find('img', class_ = 'img-fluid')['alt']
        links=property.find('a')['href']
        try:
            price= property.find('div', class_ = 'ProductPriceRating d-table-cell text-center pl-1 pr-1 align-middle').text.strip()
        except AttributeError:
            price=''
        try:
            product_brand =property.find('div',class_ ='ProductBoxProductBrand-div d-table-row text-center pl-1 pr-1 align-middle').text.strip()
        except AttributeError:
            product_brand=''
        print(name,product_brand,links,price)

        fabric = {
            'productname':name,
            'product_Brand':product_brand,
            'Product_price': price,
            'links': links,
        }    
        suit.append(fabric)
print ("Importing to Data into CSV File...!!")
df = pd.DataFrame(suit)
print("Saved Sucessfully....")
df.to_csv('Diarrhea_and_Vomiting_pagination.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You are only saving the items on the last webpage. Your list "suit" should be initialized before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

By creating the variable `suit=[]` inside the for loop, you're over-writing the existing data in each loop.

You need to declare the suit variable before the for loop

```py
...
suit=[]
for page_number in range(1, 6):
...
```